# Pixel-Perfect text stroke calculation

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the screenshot of a project I did in the past, I added a stroke around the text very nicely. But when I do it with -webkit-text-stroke, it starts to break after a level:

[image: Bad Text]

But in my previous code, I was able to do it this way.

[image: Excepted Result]

All I remember is that I think I did it with shadow and I wrote it with javascript using trigonometric functions.

My current code:

```css
.game-main-menu > div {
    @apply flex flex-col gap-y-2 font-riffic text-white text-xl;
}

.game-main-menu > div > a, button {
    @apply text-left;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 4px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px #BB5599;
    text-stroke: 4px #BB5599;
}

.game-main-menu > div > a.active {
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #E5B7D6;
    text-stroke: 2px #E5B7D6;
}
```

The way I remember my previous code

```js
function CalculateStroke(textSize, width) {
    const calculation1 = Math.sin(/* Some math in here */);
    const calculation2 = Math.cos(/* Some math in here */);
    /* ... */
    const calculation8 = Math.cos(/* Some math in here */);

    return [calculation1, calculation2, /* ... */, calculation8].join(', ');
}
// ...

element.style.textShadow = CalculateStroke(16, 4);
```

So i tried code a function but it doesn't work:

```js
function calculateStroke(textSize: number, width: number) {
    const angle = (width / textSize) * (Math.PI / 180);
    
    const sin = Math.sin(angle);
    const cos = Math.cos(angle);

    return [
        `${cos}px ${sin}px 0 #BB5599`,
        `${-cos}px ${sin}px 0 #BB5599`,
        `${cos}px ${-sin}px 0 #BB5599`,
        `${-cos}px ${-sin}px 0 #BB5599`,
    ].join(', ')
}
```

Comment: What about something like [this article](https://efedorenko.com/writing/outlining-text-with-css-and-svg)?  I don't know what font you're using, but it creates an effect like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/26vwu59m/2/), which seems pretty close to what you're looking for, and is certainly much easier to achieve.

Comment: Yes, this works, but adding svg inside the texts will make my work a bit more difficult.